# Modx invalid characters TV name

Tags: modx-revolution

No matter what I input into the TV Name field, it always comes back invalid, saying: you have invalid characters in your template variable name. I don't know how to fix this.

I'm using Modx Revo 2.2.13 on MAMP 3.0.3

Does anyone knows what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's probably a little late to answer this question a year later, but just in case someone else lands here looking for an answer, try this:

Find core/model/modx/mysql/modchunk.map.inc.php and change:

this:`'rule' => '/^(?!\\s)[a-zA-Z0-9\\x2d-\\x2f\\x7f-\\xff_-\\s]+(?!\\s)$/',`

to this:`'rule' => '/^(?!\\s)[a-zA-Z0-9\\x2d-\\x2f\\x7f-\\xff-_\\s]+(?!\\s)$/',`